# Calling a async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have a module as follows:

> async.js

```
module.exports = async function (){
    await func()
}
```

> index.js

```
var asyncFun = require('async')
```

How do i run it directly as `asyncFun()` in index.js ?

I know how to run these functions as middlewares but i want to run it directly. As for running it i need to call await and await cannot be called without being inside async.

Comment: You don't need to call await, just run asyncFunc().

Comment: you could just use the default promise syntax: `asyncFun().then( () => doSomething() )`

Comment: @Sirko can do that but the problem is there is a lot of code below and i need to use async to keep the code clean

Comment: I guess you don't need to wrap it inside async function in index.js
just return asyncFun() or const asyncData = asyncFun() should do the work.

Comment: @ChrLipp that will work asynchronously. Even if i wait for the promise to resolve i do not want to use then.

Comment: @SAGARRAVAL same as above

Comment: Of course it run asynchronously. The question was "How do i run it directly as asyncFun() in index.js" and not "how to wait for it". In the second case take YoukouleleY's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by making the root function async and wrapping all the async function with a normal function and the async function returning a promise. ( using a calling).

Example :

Assume this is the main function where you write all the code.

```
// create it as a async function
module.exports = async function main(){
    // Do something all your stuff
}
```

Call your main function from else where

```
require('./main)()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
(async () => {
    await asyncFun();
})();
```

Comment: can you provide more informations then (what `func()` refers to?)

Comment: a function which has a lot of db operations

Comment: is it async ? or not async and returns a `Promise` ?

Comment: It is async function

Comment: also in which context are you calling asyncFun ?

Comment: Every time i start my node script it has to run.

Comment: Well if you want to use the `async/await` syntax at the root of your script, my answer should fit your needs, you also have to copy the rest of your code into the lambda async function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174409/discussion-between-prajval-m-and-youkouleley).

Answer (score 0):

try adding return statement in async.js

```
module.exports = async function (){
    return await func()
}
```

and run asyncFun() directly